# How to use multiple video filters in one avconv cli

Tags: avconv

here is my cli:

```
avconv -i /home/roroco/Downloads/test_rm_watermark.mp4 -ss 0 -t 30 -vf "delogo=x=1127:y=38:w=105:h=54:band=4" -vf "delogo=x=44:y=39:w=145:h=49:band=4" -c:v libx264 -an  "/tmp/rm-watermark/test.mp4" -y
```

I hope remove two watermarks in video, but my cli only remove `delogo=x=44:y=39:w=145:h=49:band=4`, how to remove them in one cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to chain the two filters:

```
avconv -i /home/roroco/Downloads/test_rm_watermark.mp4 -ss 0 -t 30 -vf "delogo=x=1127:y=38:w=105:h=54:band=4,delogo=x=44:y=39:w=145:h=49:band=4" -c:v libx264 -an  "/tmp/rm-watermark/test.mp4" -y
```